# Using browser detection to redirect to mobile site

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, browser-detection

So i've been working with a script to redrict to another site if mobile browser is decteted. This is the code im using. But my problem is that the variable "check" always returns as true, regardless of browser. What am i doing wrong? Excuse me this is my first post.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
window.mobilecheck = function() {
    var check = false;
    (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check; 
}

if (check = true)
{
    window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com"
}

if (check = false)
{ 
    window.location = "http://www.msn.com"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Because you're not checking but assigning a value. `= != == != ===`

Comment: Feature detection, not browser detection

Comment: @Meredith: what if it's a redirect to a mobile version?

Comment: @zerkms If the screen isn't large enough to display the page properly, serve a "lighter" version of the page

Comment: @Meredith: so facebook and ebay are doing it wrong? May be we need to tell them?

Comment: @zerkms Wrong is too subjective, but it's definitely easier, more flexible, more future-proof/maintainable, and more user-friendly to feature-detect

Comment: @Meredith: well, I'm sure you won't argue that facebook is driven by amazing engineers. And they chose the separated mobile version. Which means "Feature detection, not browser detection" is too subjective. The same as "definitely easier, more flexible, more future-proof/maintainable, and more user-friendly to feature-detect". Otherwise we **must** email to facebook and tell them they are doing it in a non-maintainable way!

Comment: @zerkms—so just because eBay or Facebook do something a particular way, that makes it right? So everyone should mimic IE since MS writes far more softeware than any other browser vendor. Facebook's UI is rubbish—non–intuitive, cluttered and confusing. I wouldn't use them as a paragon of web development.

Comment: @RobG: "so just because eBay or Facebook do something a particular way, that makes it right?" --- of course not. I just tried to demonstrate that something that is subjective - is subjective. You cannot state that every time feature detection is better than a mobile site. "Facebook's UI is rubbish—non–intuitive, cluttered and confusing" --- I didn't speak about UX, from technical perspective it's state of art.

Comment: @zerkms—just pointing out the fallacy of your appeal to authority. Feature detection vs browser detection is a very old topic that has been done to death; feature detection wins hands down in every objective analysis (inclusing "mobile" vs whatever). If Facebook uses UA strings, maybe they're happy to pay the extra cost of constant updates as new UA strings emerge and really don't care (or even know?) about the failures. That's their decision, it shouldn't be foisted on others without proper consideration of the pros and cons of a particular approach for a particular case.

Comment: @RobG: "without proper consideration of the pros and cons" --- that's exactly right. Now if we have a look on the code in the question we will find that feature detection is 200% percent irrelevant to the question. So for this very question you don't need feature detection, but browser detection.

Comment: @zerkms—I understand "mobile" as "small screen, touch devices". At what screen size does the OP wish to redirect to a "mobile" site? And how does guessing the device based on the UA string of the browser being used tell you that more reliably that simply asking the device what the screen size is and detecting touch support? If the goal is easily maintained code, I'd be going for feature detection every time, otherwise there is likely a maintenance task for every new device and UA string as it appears (i.e. often).

Answer (score 1):

Without commenting on the discussion on platform vs. feature detection as a strategy, you've got several problems with your script.

First, you've declared `check` in two places, one explicit, the other implicit.  The explicit variable is inside the scope of the `mobilecheck` function, which isn't actually executed.  The other is implicitly in the global scope. Second, your implicit `check` variable is being assigned, rather than evaluated, in your if statements and the result is then evaluated.

Let's take the statement `if (check = true)`.   This is equivalent to.

```
var check = true;
if (check) { .... }
```

So, obviously, the block guarded by the if statement is being executed.

Third, you should be using better variable names.  Fourth, you shouldn't test the equivalence of a boolean variable against the literal `true` or `false`.  Given a proper name, you should just evaluate the state of the variable and it will be obvious what is being tested.   For example.

```
var isMobile = window.isMobilePlatform();
if (isMobile) {
     window.location = 'http://m.mysite.com';
}
```

A full example using your code would be something like the below.  You can see a similar working example at http://jsfiddle.net/N5HQ9/.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
(function() {
    var platform = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

    var fullExp = /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i;
    var partialExp = /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i;    

    var isMobile = fullExp.test(platform) || partialExp.test(platform.substring(0,4));

    if (isMobile) {
       window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
    } else {
       window.location = 'http://www.msn.com';
    }

})(window);

</script>
```

Comment: Im new to JS period, let alone JS inside HTML. I understand most of what your saying. Im using the check variable inside and outside the function, im not actaully ever exuctuing the function, im testing the variable againt the literal true or false, and the variable "check" is a poor choice for a variable name.

If you could, would you show me what a finished product might look like for this. Thanks

Comment: @user3743202 - updated with code sample using your expressions